# Finite group with a special property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group  with the identity element $e$ such that for each proper subgroup $H$ of $G$ there exists a unique element $g_H\in H$, $g_H\ne e$, such that the following properties hold:

(a) $g_H^2=e$;

(b) for any two distinct proper subgroups $H,K$ of $G$ we have $g_H\ne g_K$.

Then the group $G$ is abelian.

---

Thus far, I have considered a prime number $p$ dividing the order of $G$. Then, by Cauchy's theorem, there exists an element of $G$ of order $p$ and consider the subgroup $H:=\langle x\rangle=\{e,x,\dots,x^{p-1}\}$. By hypothesis, there exists $g_H=x^r$ (with $r\in \{1,\dots,p-1\}$) and $g_H^2=x^{2r}=e$. Then, we have $p\mid 2r$ and it follows $p=2$. Therefore, the order of $G$ is a power of 2.

Comment: In part (b) you are quantifying over different subgroups but before you even get to (a) or (b) you're quantifying over subgroups, so the quantifiers seem mixed up. Perhaps you're saying there exists a function $g_H$ of subgroups $H$ satisfying (a) and (b)?

Comment: @runway44: I'm puzzled about the same question. I have reproduced the problem exactly as I found it. But I'm inclined to interpret it the same you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a counterexample. As you have already shown, the order of $G$ is a power of $2$, say $|G|=2^n$. Let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. From the theory of $p$-groups, we know that $H$ is normal in $G$. Also, by property (a), $H$ contains a unique element $g_H$ of order $2$, and the subgroup $\langle g_H\rangle$ is also normal in $G$.

Let $k\in G\setminus H$, and let $K:=\langle k\rangle$. Since $G$ is not cyclic (because otherwise it would be abelian and would thus not be a counterexample), $K$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ as well and therefore contains a unique element $g_K$ of order $2$.

On the other hand, $K\neq H$, and so by property (b) we have $g_H \neq g_K$.

Since $\langle g_H\rangle$ is normal in $G$, $D:=\langle g_H, g_K\rangle$ is a group of order $4$ containing more than one element of order $2$, and thus by assumption, we have $D=G$. But then $G$ is abelian (since all groups of order $4$ are abelian), a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler way than the accepted answer.

Again as you say in the question, the group has order a power of $2.$ I claim that every element has order $2.$ Indeed, if not, there is an element $g$ of order $4.$  The subgroups generated by $g$ and $g^2$ have *the same* element of order $2$ ($g^2$) contradicting the hypothesis. So every element has order $2.$ But such a group is abelian ($ab(ba)^{-1} = a b a^{-1} b^{-1} = a b a b = (ab)^2 = e.$)

Comment: Yes, nice answer; definitely much more elegant than mine!